# $N$th-order approximation of point stabilizing diffeomorphisms by $N$th-order jet group?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-bundles, jets

*NOTE:* migrated from math SE.

I was wondering if ever higher jet groups of frames on a (possibly pseudo) Riemannian manifold $M$ approximate the point stabilizing subgroup of diffeomorphisms on $M$ as the order increases. In other words does the infinite jet group here coincide with the stabilizer of diffeomorphisms on $M$?

I know there does exist a relationship between the stabilizer of the diffeomorphism group on $M$ and jet groups on $M$ which is discussed for example in wikipedia [here][2]. In this sense jet groups are related to quotients of said stabilizer by it's subgroups which led to this line of thought in the first place. As said jet groups get larger then they would appear to indeed become closer and closer to the stabilizer of diffeomorphisms. Though that would require $\operatorname{Diff}_x^n \rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ (with quantities as defined in wiki link).

From a physics point of view, this could be exceedingly useful in finding natural "gauge-like" fields on spacetime. For example General relativity can be considered as a type of $GL(4,\mathbb{R})$ (or it's reduction to $SL(2, \mathbb{C})$ ) gauge theory. But this really could be considered a first-order approximation to the stabilizing group of diffeomorphisms on a spacetime $M$. Am I off base here or is there some merit to approximating the point-stabilizing diffeomorphism group in this manner?

In any case, I'm interested in constructing a tower of vector bundles over $M$ such that, as we proceed to higher order, we better approximate $\operatorname{Diff}_0 (M)$. Jet bundles seem like a natural way to go about this. I imagine ultimately there's a set of critera such as well-behaved and perhaps compactness which $M$ must follow.

**ADDENDUM:**

In reading the paper “[Moving Frames for Pseudo-Groups. I. The Maurer-Cartan Forms](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=527E6298CDD513D1C92C20D788615776?doi=10.1.1.409.269&rep=rep1&type=pdf)” by Olver and Pohjanpelto we find that (page 4):

> Given $z ∈ M$ , let $D^{n}_{|z} = (σ(n))−1{ z }$ denote the source jet
> fiber. The isotropy sub-group $D_{z} = { ϕ ∈ D | ϕ(z) = z }$ consists of
> all local diffeomorphisms that fix $z$. The nth order frame bundle of
> $M$ , [36], $F^{(n)} = { g(n) ∈ D^{(n)} | σ(n)(g(n)) = τ (n)(g(n)) }$ can
> be identified as the subbundle whose fibers $F^{(n)}_{|z} = D^{(n)} z ⊂
> > D^{(n)}|z$ consist of jets $g(n) = jnϕ|z$ of isotropy maps $ϕ ∈ Dz$ . For
> $n < ∞$, $F (n)$ forms a principal bundle over $M$ whose structure
> group is a finite-dimensional Lie group, namely the nth order
> prolonged linear group $GL(n)(m) = { jnϕ|0 | ϕ ∈ D(Rm)$, ϕ(0) = 0 }$
> (2.3) prescribed by n-jets of local diffeomorphisms $ϕ: Rm → Rm$ that
> fix the origin, [36; p. 139], [53, 59]. The group multiplication is
> induced by composition of diffeomorphisms.

This then seems to imply that the higher order frame bundles are the jet construction I'm looking for?  Can anyone comment on this?

[1](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=527E6298CDD513D1C92C20D788615776?doi=10.1.1.409.269&rep=rep1&type=pdf): https://chat.openai.com/share/69a017ea-43d2-4959-afec-e6b6d0198fb4 [2]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_diffeomorphism_groups

Comment: The problem as posed is, I think, the ultimate goal of geometry and as a natural consequence, of natural science. It's just, in my viewpoint, a  some kind of geometrisation theory...

Comment: What do you mean by "the stabilizer of $\mathrm{Diff}(M)$"? The terminology implies that diffeomorphisms sit in some larger space and another group is acting on it, stabilizing only the diffeomorphisms. I just don't understand in what context that would come up.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine  apologies if that is unclear. By stabilizer I meant the point stabilizer, meaning the subset of diffeomorphisms that fix a point in $M$. I thought that was standard terminology. For example a manifold may be described as the quotient of its diffeomorphism group by said stabilizer.

Comment: I think the standard terminology is what you said to describe what you meant. I could be wrong, but I think you'd have to cite some references that support the alternative terminology to show that. Anyway, any invertible (infinite) jet can be extended to a diffeomorphism (Borel lemma/Whitney extension theorem). If you take sections of the bundle of invertible infinite jets, there is no guarantee that it comes from an actual diffeomorphism (generally the section is not _holonomic_). Those sections that come from actual diffeomorphisms (_holonomic_ sections) are distinguished ...

Comment: ... by being parallel with respect to a flat connection on the _infinite_ jet bundle (the _Cartan connection_). But having that connection is of limited benefit, since it does not provide a notion of parallel transport (the corresponding transport ODE on the infinite-dimensional space jet bundle does not have unique solutions for given initial data). In fact, Borel/Whitney will give you many possible holonomic extensions for a given infinite jet datum. All of this is background info and I don't know if it helps answer your question.

Comment: Where does the Riemannian structure enter this question? Do you mean metric preserving diffeomorphism?

Comment: And by frames I assume you mean sections of the frame bundle of the manifold? And which group structure do you mean when you write "jet groups"?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold As far as which Jet construction and their consequent structure groups, well that really is part of the question, which is perhaps better stated as: **Is there a Jet construction such that the structure groups provide increasingly better approximations of $Diff_0 (M)$
as the order of the bundle increases?** Possibly relevant is pg 5 of Olver, and Pohjanpelto's work: www-users.cse.umn.edu/~olver/mf_/psI.pdf Here however they are using local diffeomorphisms

Comment: @IgorKhavkine  I get what you meant I think.  there seems to be an unfortunate dual use of holonomic and nonholonomic sections in the case of  frame bundles.  I believe your use case was more in context with applications of the homotopy principle (in the sense of Gromov)?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine Ok, I see what you mean finally.  In the finite case  the basis on $J^k M$  can be written as the set of basis on $J^{k-1} M$ and the torsion free compatible connection on $J^{k-1}M$.  In terms of jets of local diffeomorphisms $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ an approximation to the $\phi$ makes sense, but I get how at infinite order suddenly that connection doesn't make sense for what I was doing. I don't have any experience in infinite dimensions admittedly.